# Is it possible to patch a Python function at runtime (Python 3.9, REPL)?

Tags: python, decorator, bytecode, read-eval-print-loop

I am writing a library that allows people to play music live, from the REPL. It is based on some sort of recursion that allows a function to reschedule itself at some point in the future, usually as soon as it ends. I would like to simplify the syntax from this:

```py
@run()
def bip():
    Sound("bip").out()
    sleep(0.25)
    Loop(bip)
```

to

```py
@run()
def bip():
    Sound("bip").out()
    sleep(0.25)
```

The library is meant to be used by throwing code in a Python REPL, without writing down loops and beeps in a source file. Everything is meant to be used at runtime.

- `run()` is a decorator that will transfer the function definition to a scheduler and start it immediately as soon as the code is doubled-checked.
- `Loop()` is an alias for a scheduler method that will reschedule the function as soon as possible, following tempo and time constraints.

How could I get rid of `Loop()`? Is it possible to programmatically add `Loop()` to any function decorated by `run()`? Is it possible to alter the source code of a function evaluated directly in a Python REPL?

It is a nice programming problem that I haven't found a solution to yet..

EDIT: Here is the definition of the `run()` decorator.

```py
def run(beat=1, bar=1):

    def run_inner(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            """
            We need to catch errors before they stop the program when the user
            submits incorrect code. This ugly decorator will catch 90% of the
            current errors made by users when submitting new functions to the
            scheduler.
            """

            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)

            except NameError as e:
                print("You named something incorrectly: {}.".format(e))
                Stop(func)
                return None
            except ValueError as e:
                print("Check your numbers: {}.".format(e))
                Stop(func)
                return None
            except TypeError as e:
                print("Something ended up in the wrong pipe: {}.".format(e))
                Stop(func)
                return None
            except AttributeError as e:
                print("Whoops. Correct your code please : {}.".format(e))
                Stop(func)
                return None

        """
        Track._memory is a dictionary holding the name, bytecode, etc...
        of all the functions currently running on the scheduler. A function
        can only be started if it is not already registered so we check here.
        """

        if func.__name__ not in list(Track._memory.keys()):

            # Start will register / schedule the function for immediate 
            # execution.
            Start(func_wrapper, beat=0, bar=1)

        return func_wrapper
    return run_inner
```

Comment: Where are `run` and `Loop` defined?

Comment: `run()` is defined in the `__init__.py`file and `Loop()` is an alias to `Track.instant_loop()`, defined in the class `Track` in another file. I choosed not to include them in the question because I would like to know if manipulating the bytecode or some internal representation of the source code of an interpreted function is possible.

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] your question to include the definition of `run` at least. Can you not edit `__init__.py`?

Comment: I just added the `run()` decorator definition. Why would I edit `__init__.py`? I'm not sure to understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: You're not using `run` as a decorator. There's no `@` on it, so you just run `run`, then define an unrelated function immediately afterwards.

Comment: My bad, it was another mistake made when writing the post but you might have guessed that I am indeed using `run()` as a decorator.